# How to exclude a particular System framework from my cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am running a Cocoa application and need to use my own authentication related libraries. However the cocoa project by default loads the System frameworks which contain Kerberos and GSS authentication libraries  (System/libraries/Framework/Kerberos.framework and System/Libraries/Framework/GSS.framework ) . I need to remove references or unlink these particular frameworks. Can anybody help me figure out how to remove them?